# Свечение текста

Tags: html, css, css3

Как реализовать такое свечение текста ссылки?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это тень текста...  `text-shadow`

Comment: посмотри вот тут примеры https://codepen.io/FelixRilling/pen/qzfoc

Answer (score 2):

Это просто размазанная тень текста. В общем случае выглядит так:

> text-shadow: [тень справа]px [тень снизу]px [насколько размазано]px цвет;

Если положительные пиксели ставят тень в указанных направлениях ОТ текста, то отрицательные значения перевернут тень в противоположном направлении. В вашем случае, надо отбросить тени во всех 4-х направлениях, чередуя их через запятую:

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/7wyjp4cm/) (надо немного поиграться с цветами)

```css
body {background-color: #112}

.light {
  color: #eff; 
  font-size: 20px; 
  cursor: pointer; 
  font-family: 'Helvetica';
  display: inline-block; margin: 20px;
}

.light:hover {
  color: #aff;
  text-shadow: 
     5px  5px 10px #045acf,  /*  Нижний - Справа */
     5px -5px 10px #045acf,  /*  Нижний - Слева  */
    -5px  5px 10px #045acf,  /* Верхний - Справа */
    -5px -5px 10px #045acf;  /* Верхний - Слева  */
}
```

```html
<div class="light">УСЛУГИ</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Есть еще вариант с помощью `filter: blur();`

```css
div.parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 68px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 34px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #005e8b;
  border-radius: 25%;
  filter: blur(15px);
}

div.parent span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <span>Текст</span>
</div>
```